# Login issue in android app when app is in open status

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

When I login to my android application for the first time, its works perfectly, after I logout, when I try to login its doesn't open the activity,
I have cleared FragmentStack and saved preferences below.

```
clearFragmentStack();
clearSavedPrefs();
```

But When i disable or destroy the application from recent apps or delete data from settings. its working normally.

How can I solve this issue. Please find the code below.

```
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // User clicked OK button
        httpClientService.canCanLogout(new ResponseCallBack<BaseDao>() {
            @Override
            public void onDataReceived(
                HttpResponseHolder<BaseDao> responseHolder) {
                    if (responseHolder.getErrReason() != null) {
                        generalProperListener.showShortToastMessage(responseHolder.getErrReason());
                    } else {
                        startUserLoginFragment();
                        ct.event.push("Logout");
                    }
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: use shared preferences to create session like functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleared the answer.

Where I have concat the previous string value.

```
//old
UserAddress.ADDR_URL +="?".concat(paramsString);

//new
UserAddress.ADDR_URL =URL+"?".concat(paramsString);
```